# Xgboost how label categories respond to each variable identified from xgb.importance?

Tags: r, plot, xgboost

I made a model:

```
model<-xgboost(data=as.matrix(data[,-1]),label=data$Ethnicity, num_class=8, nrounds=50,objective="multi:softmax",lambda=1, eval_metric="merror")
```

**data** is a matrix of 94 variables of random survey question and **Ethnicity** is a 0-7 variable coding race/ethnicity so that every number from 0 to 7 represents an ethnicity.

I found which variables are most important in the prediction:

```
xgb.importance(model=model)
```

I get:

```
##     Feature         Gain        Cover   Frequency
##  1:     q97 0.0924173556 0.0388402250 0.016981237
##  2:      q9 0.0603595554 0.0199381316 0.012749847
##  3:      q7 0.0456855077 0.0447756304 0.066922777
##  4:      q6 0.0436987577 0.0485072162 0.041311731
##  5:      q8 0.0319606309 0.0212999077 0.015199599
##  6:     q99 0.0276115402 0.0201090242 0.007961695
##  7:     q89 0.0245865711 0.0249913356 0.023829408
##  8:     q13 0.0197648132 0.0190748590 0.010912533
##  9:     q81 0.0194462208 0.0140010066 0.021880742
## 10:     q71 0.0192126872 0.0194684164 0.019709370
```

However as you can see my response is multi-class, i.e. all 7 ethnicity groups at once. My question is how do I use plots to show **how each ethnic group respond to each variable identified** or **to fit individual models to see what variables are important for each ethnicity** in my above xgb.importance? TIA!

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this in R. What you can do is do it for each class vs the rest of the classes with the help of a loop. Not exactly similar but you can find some related answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637145/gbm-r-function-get-variable-importance-separately-for-each-class

Comment: hey mate the link you sent was on glm not xgboost.

Comment: Yes. I was pointing out the method. Can you share your sample data with ```dput()```? Or with an attached link in the question? Then we will be in a better position to help you out.